# Using python with bash

Tags: python, bash, popen

```
import os
ot = os.popen("%s") %"ls"
```

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'file' and 'str'
```

I can not figure it out why error occurs. I mean it's pure string operation, right?  Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean `os.popen("%s" % "ls")`? What you've got now tries to apply `%` to *the result of* `os.popen("%s")` (hence ‘`'file'`’ in the error) and `"ls"` (‘`'str'`’). And what has this got to do with Bash?!

Comment: is ls the file name or the command you want to execute in bash and get results here ?

Comment: You are right, the % str should be touched after "%s" , can not be separated or  comes error...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is great because of the interactive shell.

Try:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.popen("%s")
<open file '%s', mode 'r' at 0x10d020390>
```

You can see the error in front of you. The result of `os.popen` is a file. You are then applying a string operation to that.

Translating what you have to what I *think* you are trying to do, try:

```
>>> os.popen("%s" % "ls").read()
```

Or, directly:

```
>>> os.popen("ls").read()
```

But the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is usually preferred:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output("ls")
```

Comment: Oh...Yes, I mixed up... Thanks very much...haha

Comment: @PuMing.Z: or just `os.listdir()`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes. that's a better choice. Thanks.